# Background color in Dialog does not show properly

Tags: android, layout, dialog, android-linearlayout, background-color

I used Dialog in my app and sets its layout from xml. When I use the below code it works properly (background color).

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size40"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I use the below code it does not work properly. I tested it in Hwawei TIT-AL00 (Android version 5.1)

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size40"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?android:colorPrimary">

</LinearLayout>
```

Its background color does not show. My project minSdkVersion is 21. I need to use

```
android:background="?android:colorPrimary
```

because of my some requirements. Dialog has no custom style and The style I used in activity class is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you add more details? Whats your app theme and activity theme?

Comment: @Vishu I edited my question

Comment: This looks fine. Can you check if you are applying any theme to activity? You can also try    `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"`

Comment: Maybe it's better to set it programmatically

Comment: @Vishu thanks a lot. It works fine

Answer (score 1):

Please try 'android:background="?attr/colorPrimary'